# "Array-like objects" ¿Qué son; cómo identificarlos?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

No soy un experto en inglés, pero leyendo sobre ES6 me he encontrado en varias ocasiones que hacen mención de los *Array-like objects* (sobre todo cuando leo sobre *Map*, *Set*, *WeakMap*, *WeakSet*), como en el siguiente contexto:

> **Other collections support for-of too**
>
> `for–of` is not just for arrays. It also works on most array-like objects, like DOM NodeLists.

Por lo poco que alcanzo a comprender, se me figura algo así como lo que devuelve jQuery cuando consultan una lista de elementos con (ejemplo) `$('a')`.

Entiendo que de por si un **Array** ya es un objeto, pero ¿a qué se refiere el termino *Array-like object*?, ¿cómo creo uno?, ¿cuál es la finalidad en comparación a un arreglo?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un *array-like object* es un objeto que se asemeja a un arreglo porque representa un conjunto de elementos y tiene una propiedad `length`, sin embargo no poseen directamente los [métodos](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2015/12/metodos-map-filter-y-sort-en-javascript/) de `Array.prototype` que son muy útiles como `sort`, `filter`, etc.

Un ejemplo muy común de este tipo de objetos es `arguments` que hace referencia a los argumentos que se envían a una función:

```
funtion foo(a, b) {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
}

foo(1, 2); // imprime 1
```

Al no poder invocar directamente algún método de `Array.prototype` lo que hacemos es primero convertirlo a un arreglo:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

El método `slice` tiene la habilidad de trabajar con *array-like objects* y por eso es posible la conversión.

Otros ejemplos son los objetos del DOM obtenidos a través de métodos como `document.getElementsByClassName`, conocidos como `NodeList`. Esta es una forma alternativa de convertir a arreglo:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('.tuClase'),
var nodeArray = [].slice.call(nodeList);
```

Idealmente no tienes que crear este tipo de objetos, siempre será más fácil utilizar arreglos cuando necesites una colección de elementos, esto facilita la integración de un programa en un proyecto, ya que si todas las funciones usan arreglos no hay necesidad de hacer conversiones. Simplemente hay que estar consciente de qué son y sus diferencias con los arreglos.