# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre "new Array() / new Object()" y "[] / {}" respectivamente?

Tags: javascript

En javascript hay dos formas de crear *arreglos* y *objetos*, se pueden crear mediante objetos literales:

1. `new Array()` - Objeto - arreglo
2. `new Object()` - Objeto - objeto

ó bien se pueden crear a partir de sus objetos primitivos los cuales son:

1. `[]` - Objeto - arreglo
2. `{}` - Objeto - objeto

¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar usar el *objeto literal* a usar el objeto primitivo?

> Entiendo que para el `new Array()`, el constructor puede recibir un párametro para definir la propiedad `length` del arreglo creado, pero **¿es esta la única diferencia?**

Comment: Una diferencia grande es la velocidad de compilación y ejecución de la segunda frente a la primera. Aquí hay un ejemplo explicativo (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array)

Comment: @Héctor no hacía falta que borrases la respuesta. La idea es que la editases y la completases no borrarla

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta es muy amplia o en su defecto falta mencionar lo buscado/investigado. Por ejemplo, en este sitio ya se tiene la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2511/65 ¿lo has leído? ¿hay algo que no ha quedado claro sobre ella?

Comment: @Ruben No me parece que esa pregunta se relacione con la mía

Comment: En cuanto lo buscado/investigado podrías mencionar las preguntas que encontraste en este sitio y por qué no se relacionan/responden  tu pregunta (: La que puse aparecía en los enlaces en la sección "Relacionados" del panel derecho, y lo puse a manera de ejemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recopilando diferencias he encontrado:

- La que tu comentas. El constructor, efectivamente new Array permite añadir el tamño del array.
- La velocidad. La ejecución de los literales en javaScript es prácticamente el doble de rápida. Se pueden seguir los sigueintes token de operación que ejemplifican los diferentes pasos que ejecuta el compilador a la hora de realizar una u otra operación.

  ```
  []: ARRAY_INIT  
  [1]: ARRAY_INIT (NUMBER)  
  [1, foo]: ARRAY_INIT (NUMBER, IDENTIFIER)  
  new Array: NEW, IDENTIFIER  
  new Array(): NEW, IDENTIFIER, CALL  
  new Array(5): NEW, IDENTIFIER, CALL (NUMBER)  
  new Array(5,4): NEW, IDENTIFIER, CALL (NUMBER, NUMBER)  
  new Array(5, foo): NEW, IDENTIFIER, CALL (NUMBER, IDENTIFIER)
  ```

  Siendo:

  ARRAY_INIT -> Una inicialización simple
  IDENTIFIER -> La idneitficación por parte del compilador del objeto Array
  CALL -> La llamada al constructor
  () -> Elemenos del cosntructor, que producen diferentes salidas para uno y otro.
- El literal genera un "runtime array" mientras que Array() genera un objeto con funciones que dan acceso de array, esto provoca ciertas limitaciones a la hora de acceder a métodos.

En resumen usa siempre que puedas los literales, pues tiene bastantes ventajas frente al objeto.

Comment: Genial. Voy a borrar los comentarios para que no ensucien la respuesta

Answer (score -2):

Entiendo que tanto array como string heredan de la clase Object en Javascript.

En primera instancia te diría que String se usa para campos de texto en HTML, a los que se pueden aplicar estilos para campos Text y funciones para String.

Y array a mi criterio se usan para datos mas complejos, como anidar uno o varios elementos html (tipo object), incluso manejar un árbol de objetos. Esto es muy util cuando trabajamos con grillas por ejemplo.

Te dejo mas info con los distintos métodos y propiedades, espero que te sea útil!!

String (Object) Javascript:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ecczf11c(v=vs.94).aspx

Array (Object) Javascript:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k4h76zbx(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Me falto aclarar: String NO es un vector de String, String es un vector de Char, es decir, si a una variable String le asigno el valor "Hola" me lo va a considerar como un Vector de caracteres de 4 posiciones, cada uno tendrá 1 letra. Espero que te sirva esta info.

Comment: Hola @seojedaperez tecnicámente en javascript todo es un objeto!

Comment: Así es.. espero que se entienda la diferencia entre uno y otro :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia si te fijas bien, en ningun momento dije lo contrario, de hecho he mencionado que las cadenas de caracteres heredan directamente de Object. Saludos.

Comment: @OscarGarcia he dicho que string puede ser usado como un vector de Char, eso no quita que sea un objeto y herede de object, de hecho este concepto se usa en varios lenguajes de programación... me parece genial que complementes con información, pero si solamente vas a responder para replicarme, te pido que te tomes 2 minutos para digerir la información afín de que no malinterpretes lo que estoy diciendo. Saludos!

Comment: String tiene metodos tales como IndexOf, Length, CharAt, de hecho se puede recorrer usando (String)[(posicion del vector/string)], y te devolverá un tipo de dato Char. Esto es algo muy basico que existe desde que existe la programación orientada a objetos: el tipo de dato String deja de ser un dato primitivo y pasa a ser un dato Object de tipo Vector que puede recorrerse carácter por carácter. La verdad que no voy a borrar nada por que creo que te puede ayudar a mejorar como programador toda esta info. Espero que te sea util!

Comment: Cuando tengas tiempo proba esto: "Hola Mundo"[1] te devolverá "H". Con esto queda demostrado que el tipo de dato String puede ser recorrido como vector sin aplicar ningún tipo de logica rara.

Comment: Recién leo lo que pusiste del DOM: String en Javascript es considerado un elemento text del DOM, lamento que no te hayas tomado los minutos necesarios para leer los links que puse de ejemplo, alli se ve claramente como se le puede añadir estilos del tipo fontcolor, fontsize, bold, italic, big, etc, espero que no los repliques por que es información oficial de Microsoft, que creo que tiene algo de autoridad en el asunto...

Comment: Te adjunto el link y ojala  puedas recapacitar y cambiar el puntaje que me asignaste, dado que he invertido tiempo en enseñarte cosas nuevas :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ecczf11c(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Tú ganas. Borro mis mensajes. Veo que te cierras en banda y no entiendes que intento sacarte de tu error. Suerte, un saludo.

Comment: Te pido mil disculpas, estoy trabajando a full, tengo la entrega de un sistema para mañana. Me hubiera gustado seguir la discusión, pero me consume mucho tiempo de desarrollo (que no tengo). Sea como sea, luego de leer mas en detalle este post me doy cuenta que la pregunta no mencionaba String/Array, sino Array/Object. Sinceramente mi idea era facilitar una ayuda a un usuario que lo necesitara, por alguna razon derivo en una discusion que me doy cuenta, ni siquiera se relaciona con su pregunta, asi que el tiempo dedicado a contestar fue en vano. saludos.

Comment: No importa, disculpa también mi insistencia, lo importante es la intención y el tiempo que invertiste (por cierto, piensa en el ejemplo que te di, es muy ilustrativo: `var c = 'HOLA'; console.log(c[2]); c[2] = 'b'; console.log(c[2]);` ). Para evitar que te sigan poniendo negativos (conforme pase el tiempo y la gente visite este mensaje es probable que sigas recibiendo más), te recomiendo borrar o editar la respuesta.